# writing to multiple open textstreams

Tags: vb.net, filesystemobject

I am new to vb.net.  I have much experience using vb 6.  What I am wanting to know is how to replace the file system object.  Specificaly I am wanting to use textstream arrays.  How would I write the following in vb.net

For simplicity reasons I am going with the assumptions that I have a text file that is 1 byte long and is just a repating series of #'s from 0 to 9.  I want any record that has a 1 to go to tsout(1), 2 to tsout(2) ect...

```
dim fso as new filesystemobject, tsIN as textstream, tsOut(10) as textstream
dim lineIN, i
set tsin = fso.opentextfile("C:\input.txt",forreading,false)
for i = 1 to 10
 set tsout(i) = fso.createtextfile("C:\output" & i & ".txt",true)
next
do while not tsin.atendofstream
 linein = mid(tsin.readline,1,1)
 tsout(linein).writeline(linein)
loop
for i = 1 to 10
 tsout(i).close
next
tsin.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.IO.StreamWriter`s and `System.IO.StreamReader`s:

```
Using in As New StreamReader("C:\input.txt")
    Dim out(9) As StreamWriter

    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        out(i) = New StreamWriter("C:\output" & i & ".txt")
    Next

    While in.Position < in.Length
        Dim l As Integer = Integer.Parse(in.ReadLine().Substring(1, 1))

        out(l).WriteLine(l.ToString())
    End while

    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        out(i).Close()
        out(i).Dispose()
    Next
End Using
```

Note: This assumes `Imports System.IO` at the beginning of your file, or project-wide.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank you very much, i had asked several other people that i worked with and they all were supposed to know vb.net and none of them had any clue as to how to do this in 6, .net or any other language.  your help is most appreciated